# How to add artificial sampling jitter to an audio file with Python?

Tags: audio, jitter

I need to do audio augmentation with Python and would like to add sampling jitter to my audio. Example what jitter sounds like can be found here: http://www.sereneaudio.com/blog/what-does-jitter-sound-like
Note: I don't mean to add simply random noise.

I looked up common audio libraries like librosa and torchaudio, but could not find any suitable modules.

Comment: Hi torchaudio maintainer here - Unfortunately, torchaudio does not support this.